# How can I convert to milliseconds in ngModel?

Tags: javascript, html, date, angular

This is my HTML:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="ask.start" type="number" min="0"/>
```

I need to use `type="number"` because user will have a question like

> "In how many days do you want to see this"

then comes the `input`.

the `[(ngModel)]` value is number of days. I need to convert it to milliseconds somehow, so I can get the milliseconds value and store it.

EDIT: the formula for 1 day in ms is `24 * 60 * 60 * 1000`

How can I do this? I've been loosing my mind over this for days now.

Thanks.

Comment: one way is to use the Date object https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: How? Please provide an example. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create a custom pipe.

```
@Pipe({ name: 'myPipe'})
export class MyPipe implements PipeTransform{
  transform(val) {
    return val * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
  } 
}
```

Change your input like this:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="ask.start | myPipe" type="number" min="0"/>
```

Related question: [Using Pipes within ngModel on INPUT Elements in Angular2-View](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39642882/2641361)

Comment: Give me a minute, please.

Comment: I'm receiving this error: `Cannot have a pipe in an action expression at column 31 in...`

Comment: Have you added something like (ngModelChange)="value=$event" ? Otherwise your desired value doesn't reach the pipe.

Comment: Refer to this plunker example for assistance: https://plnkr.co/edit/0CQVXl1Y9UsDp5TCszSk?p=preview

Comment: No I haven't.. Is there some other way to get milliseconds from type="number"?

Comment: @eric.dummy you've a smell in your design then :) Go back to the Angular 2 tutorial and create an input from scratch. Afterwards apply your custom pipe.

Comment: probably.. but is there a way to bypass this? Thanks :)

Comment: @eric.dummy you shouldn't bypass stuff. Stick to best-practices and everything works beautiful :) Back to the drawing board, I dare you.

Comment: Care to continue in chat? :)