# Angular 2 How to use pipes on input field in case of two way binding

Tags: html, typescript, pipe, angular2-template, angular-ngmodel

I know this is similar or duplicate to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39643180/2517223) ,  I  want to use pipe on ngmodel like this `[ngModel]="item.value | currency:'USD$'"` but i have a scenario where I need to bind a method like this `(ngModelChange)="someMethod()"` instead of setting the value `(ngModelChange)="item.value=$event"`. How to achieve both of them together.

My Code:

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="item.value | currency:'USD$'"  (ngModelChange)="someMethod()" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```html
<input type="text" [ngModel]="item.value | currency:'USD$'"  (ngModelChange)="someMethod($event)" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing square bracket from ngModel and see if that helps. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Drop the parenthesis like so, and pass the event to your method.

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="item.value | currency:'USD$'"  (ngModelChange)="someMethod()" />
```

Then in your .ts file you can assign the value:

```
someMethod(event) {
    item.value = event;
    //Other stuff you were doing before
}
```