# Using pipe in AngularJS mg-model and formatting the date

Tags: angular, typescript, pipe

```
<p>Original format: {{ item.expires_at }}</p> # 2019-06-30T23:30:01+00:00
```

Formatted date in input element becomes non-editable so unfortunately I cannot edit it. Is there a way to achieve this?

```
<input type="text" ng-model="item.expires_at | date:'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss'">
```

Having no front-end skills doesn't help but as far as I can see from some answers, we can use example below. However, when I use it, I get no data in input so input element is just empty.

Ref: [Using Pipes within ngModel on INPUT Elements in Angular2-View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39642882/using-pipes-within-ngmodel-on-input-elements-in-angular2-view)

```
<input type="text"
[ngModel]="item.expires_at | date:'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss'"
(ngModelChange)="item.expires_at=$event" />
```

I read [Template Syntax](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#!#expression-operators) but couldn't find a solution.

Comment: you want in angular1 or angular 2?

Comment: Looks like Angular2 is being used.

Comment: are you using grid or not?

Comment: I don't know what grid is:( I am not a front-end dev. How do I find out if my code uses it or not? I am dealing with someone else's code.

Comment: try this `[ngModel]="{{item.expires_at | date:'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss}}"` and let me know

Comment: Input is empty in that case.

Comment: it will be shown NaN. You should need input or null not empty

Comment: This is what I see when I inspect the element: `[ngmodel]="15/08/2055 16:52:01"` However, I don't see anything visually.

Comment: then somewhere you has been hide this part. check your code :)

Comment: There is no hide feature enabled anywhere in the code.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the DatePipe in the Controller.

I Suggest you add an onChange method to your controller. 
Your component class would look something like this:

```
export class MyComponent {

 ...
 expires_formatted;

 constructor(private datePipe: DatePipe)) {
 }

 onChange(expires_at: string) {
   this.expires_formatted = this.datePipe.transform(expires_at, 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss');
 }

 ...

}
```

And then in the template use

```
<input type="text"
[ngModel]="item.expires_at"
(ngModelChange)="onChange($event)" />
```

Comment: How do I adapt it to my controller though? As I mentioned, I have zero Angular knowledge. Controller looks like this: `'use strict';

module.exports = [
    ...
    '$scope',
    '$timeout',
     userService
     ...
    function(
        ...
        $scope,
        $timeout,
        userService,
        ...
    ) {
        ...
    });`

Comment: Ok, I was aiming for a Angular.io (Angular2) solution but your are obviously using Angular.js. But the approach would be similar I believe.

You will have to inject '$filter' in your controller. (I believe you just have to add '$filter' and $filter respectively in the two line you mentionend in your comment.

Inside the controller you will add a function onChange() to the scope.
`$scope.onChange = function (expires_at) { return $filter('date')(expires_at, 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss');} `

Hope this helps. I'm not so sure about angular.js anymore.