# Angular Uppercase/Lowercase Pipe - Why not just use css?

Tags: angular, piping

Why do the uppercase/lowercase pipes exist in Angular?

Any situation I can think of that they would be used for you could just use the below CSS instead:

```
text-transform: uppercase|lowercase
```

Any examples for using this in pipe in production where the text-transform in css wouldn't work or be the best solution?

Comment: Sometimes you want to work with data, sometimes you want to work with presentation.

Comment: I guess if you want users to be able to copy the text in upper/lowercase, crawlers to see it, perhaps pass it to a child components input, etc.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is why:

```js
console.log($("input").val());
```

```css
input{
 text-transform: lowercase;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" value="EXAMPLE" />
```

If you use a pipe to lowercase, then the value will be lowercase.

So if you aren't using an input field or don't intend on extracting the data from an element, then I would say just to use css - at least then you will only have to define this in 1 place (ideally), compared to having to explicitly use a pipe in all fields which is an [extensibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensibility) nightmare for larger applications.

---

If you want to see a working angular example of this, check this question: [Using Pipes within ngModel on INPUT Elements in Angular2-View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39642882/using-pipes-within-ngmodel-on-input-elements-in-angular2-view)