# Angular 2 Pipe on form input

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I'm missing something.

Have a pipe on a phone number input.  The pipe adds in the paraphrases and dash as you type.

```
<ion-input type="tel" name="cellPhone" id="cellPhone" [(ngModel)]="phoneNumber" name="cellPhone" id="cellPhone" value="{{phoneNumber|phoneMask}}"></ion-input>
```

Getting an error

> ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed
>   after it was checked. Previous value: '1'. Current value: '(1'.

I know it has to deal with the binding of cellphone.  Not sure which end to fix.

Comment: try removing the value attribute and assigning the pipe to ngModel

Comment: This answer solved it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39642882/using-pipes-within-ngmodel-on-input-elements-in-angular2-view