# How to use PercentPipe in input field

Tags: angular, angular7, angular-pipe

I am trying to create input field for percentage. And I am using PercentPipe to display percentage. However I am getting error when I input some number

```
<input required type="number" min="0" max="100"
   [ngModel]="viewModel.value | percent:'1.2'" id="limitPercentage"
   (ngModelChange)="viewModel.value=$event"
   [formControl]="viewModel.control"
   name="limitPercentage" class="form-control"
   (showErrorMessage)="showErrorMessage($event)"
/>
```

Error in console:

```
 ERROR Error: InvalidPipeArgument: '0% is not a number' for pipe 'PercentPipe'
```

Comment: You can't use pipes like that. Here's a good thread about why you're getting that error along with some workarounds: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39643180/9901630

Answer (score 2):

I found that using the percentpipe was no good for inputs.

I am storing the VAT(Tax rate) rate as a float in my db, but I wanted to show this as a percentage on the product edit form. I suspect it would be confusing otherwise.

So the percentpipe isn't a great fit as it transforms numbers into text strings. Now I guess I could have transformed the number back on save, but I wanted to use the number spinner in the input and to handle the validation.

So this is what I ended up with...

1) in the form I have a input

```
    <mat-form-field class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-2" >
      <mat-label>VAT rate </mat-label>
      <input type="number" matInput formControlName="prodVatRate" 
             min="0" max="100" pattern ="^0?[0-9]?[0-9]$|^(100)$">
          <span matPrefix>%&nbsp;</span>
        </mat-form-field>
```

2) in the component I have a couple of simple functions to handle the transform.

```
toPercent(floatingNumber: number): number  {
   return floatingNumber * 100;
}

toDecimal(integerNumber: number): number {
    return integerNumber / 100;
}
```

they are so simple you might want to add them inline.

3) I'm using reactive forms so at page load I "patchValue" the form with the http response...

```
this.productForm.patchValue({
  prodVatRate: this.toPercent(this.product.prodVatRate),
  ... more data inserted here
});
```

4) and finally in my form save / submit, I transform the data back to a float.

```
    const p = { ...this.product, ...this.productForm.value };

    // change the Vat rate back to a floating point number
    p.prodVatRate = this.toDecimal(p.prodVatRate);
```

I hope it helps you out.

Comment: If not in loading phase to patch value, you can add `(focusout)`  method. It means that move the step 3 into `(focusout)`  method.

Answer (score -1):

Do it with a method in your component.

First import and add the pipe in the constructor, also create a transform method.

```
import { PercentPipe } from '@angular/common';

class YourComponent {

  constructor(private percentPipe: PercentPipe) {}

  toPercent(value) {
    return this.percentPipe.transform(value, '1.2');
  }
}
```

You will need to add the provider in the provider list in your module if not, you will recieve an exeption

```
providers: [PercentPipe,...]
```