# Percent Pipe in Input control using FormControlName

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-pipe

I'd like to format the value inside the textbox with a percent pipe, so that 0.42 shows up as 42%.  I'd like to do this initially, as well as when the user changes the value.

```js
public myFormGroup: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
    myNumber: new FormControl(0.42)
});
```

```html
<div [FormGroup]="myFormGroup">
  <input formControlName="myNumber">
</div>
```

But I don't see a way to do this.  Initial google searches produced results like this one: [How to use pipes in Angular 5 reactive form input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49522542/how-to-use-pipes-in-angular-5-reactive-form-input), which seems a bit overly complicated for such a simple use case.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transform the value (using pipe) during form initialization and also when the value changes

```js
 this.form = this.fb.group({
      myNumber: [this.percentPipe.transform(0.42)]
    })
    
  setValue(): void {
    const input = this.form.controls.myNumber.value;
    this.form.controls.myNumber.setValue(this.percentPipe.transform(input));
  }
```

```html
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <input type="text" formControlName="myNumber" (change)="setValue()">
</form>
```