# date pipe with ngModel in angular 5

Tags: angular

I am binding input element with model property in angular 5

```
<input [(ngModel)]="MB.YearOfOperation | date: 'dd-MMM-yyyy' " type="text" class="form-control">
```

Using date pipe to format its value but it gives error

> Cannot have a pipe in an action expression at column 33

so I tried below approach with (ngModelChange)

```
<input [(ngModel)]="MB.YearOfOperation | date: 'dd-MMM-yyyy' " (ngModelChange)="MB.YearOfOperation =$event" type="text" class="form-control">
```

But still it give the same error , How can I use pipes with [(ngModel)] ??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Pipes within ngModel on INPUT Elements in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39642882/using-pipes-within-ngmodel-on-input-elements-in-angular)

Answer (score 5):

You should not use pipe with two way databinding, if you really want to use it with ngModel, you should consider one way data binding with **`ngModelChange`**  as follows,

```
[ngModel]="MB.YearOfOperation | date: 'dd-MMM-yyyy'" (ngModelChange)="updateDate($event)"
```

Comment: No , I wrote a function updateDate() to return Date value in required format  but MB.YearOfOperation is going as null in updateDate()