# Using currency pipe does not work as intended on ion-input

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, angular-pipe

I am trying to use the `currency` pipe on an `ion-input` element as follows.

```
<ion-input type="number" name="amount" 
 [ngModel]="myObject.amount | currency" 
 (ngModelChange)="myObject.amount = $event">
</ion-input>
```

When I use this [one-way binding + event approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39642882/using-pipes-within-ngmodel-on-input-elements-in-angular/39643180), the input field is blank on the UI. If I inspect element, I see the `ng-reflect-model="$100"` attribute value on the generated `input` element. If I change the `type` to text, however, I do see the rendered value of $100.

```
<ion-input type="text" name="amount" 
 [ngModel]="myObject.amount | currency" 
 (ngModelChange)="myObject.amount = $event">
</ion-input>
```

The problem is now I lose the numeric keyboard if `type="text"` instead of `type="number"`. Any ideas on how to make this work with showing the numeric keyboard?

I am using ionic-angular v3.9.2.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this,

```
<ion-input type="number" name="amount" 
 [ngModel]="myObject.amount"
 (change)="updateAmount($event.target.value)">
</ion-input>
```

and in the .ts

```
updateAmount(qp:number):void {
   this.formattedAmount = this.currencyPipe.transform(this.amount, 'USD');
   element.target.value = this.formattedAmount;
}
```

Comment: Where is `this.currencyPipe` coming from? Also, where is `element` coming from? Could you please give a more complete example for the `.ts` file?

Comment: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ion-input-with-ngmodel-and-pipe/50206/2

Comment: both the examples will give you a better idea

Comment: Thanks, but the plnkr example doesn't work (it gets stuck in loading) and plus you're using `type=text` and I don't know if that's going to translate to ionic. The second example on that forum doesn't work either when `type=number`.