# How to check for changes with pipes? Angular text area

Tags: javascript, html, json, angular

I have a text area with formatted json. the user is allowed to make changes in that text area. However because of the json pipe I can't use `[(ngmodel)}`. Also `(change)` and `(ngModelChange)` don't seem to trigger anything. How do I capture the user changes?

```
data: string = '{"a":1,"b":2,"c":{"d":3, "e":4}}';

ngOninit(){
this.data= JSON.parse(this.data);
}

 saveUserChanges(){
 console.log(this.data)
}
```

**HTML**

```
<text area (ngModelChange)="saveUserChanges()">{{data | json}}</textarea>
<button (click)="saveUserChanges()">save</button>
```

Comment: It's `(ngModelChange)` (an event handler) not `[(ngModelChange)]` (a binding). And since the text area's `[(ngModel)]` is not bound to a value, the `ngModelChange` event will not be emitted when the content changes.

Comment: How do I use `[(ngModel)]` with the pipe: `| json`

Comment: Why do you need `JsonPipe`? It appears that `data` is a `String`.

Comment: That's to format it nicely once I parse it

Comment: You can inject your pipe into the component class and call .transform on it to format the json inside the component class

Comment: how so @vinaayakh?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Pipes within ngModel on INPUT Elements in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39642882/using-pipes-within-ngmodel-on-input-elements-in-angular)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bind the value with `[ngModel]` and set the new value with `(ngModelChange)`:

```
<textarea [ngModel]="data | json" (ngModelChange)="saveUserChanges($event)"></textarea>
```

In the component class, `saveUserChanges` is defined as:

```
saveUserChanges(value) {
  this.data = JSON.parse(value);
}
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rmerdc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) for a demo.