# Formatting date time in ngModel in form with Angular date pipe

Tags: html, angular, datetime, formatdatetime

I have this below where `birthDate` is "1938-08-08T00:00:00" and I want it to be "dd/MM/yyyy", but I can't seem to figure out how to use the Angular date pipe in `ngModel`.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="ex. MM/DD/YYYY" [(ngModel)]=matterData.birthDate name="birthDate">
```

I tried this with no luck:

```
[(ngModel)]={{matterData.birthDate | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy'}}
```

The only way I can get it to work is if I format the date in the .ts code first with Angular 'formatDate()'

Comment: Don't you just love standards?

Answer (score 4):

I don't understand why you want to format it inside a ngModel.

One way data binding (Interpolation {{}})doesn't work inside a two way databinding. If you want to use pipe, I would instead suggest to use a value attribute instead of ngModal.

Your HTML should look like:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="ex. MM/DD/YYYY" [value]="matterData.birthDate | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy'" name="birthDate">
```

Here is a live example for the same. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ubpthb

Comment: if I do this, then when I make a change to the field, my "editForm.dirty" which is form #editForm="ngForm" never becomaes dirty!

Comment: You can use touched function as an alternative. like -->
if(editForm.dirty || editForm.touched)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. You're saying check if it's dirty or touched? What I want it to have it change from not dirty to dirty or not touched to touched! Can I set the editForm.dirty to true in the .ts file? How would I do that?

Comment: Why do you want .dirty? are you doing any validation? If so what validation is required? Did you try editForm.pristine variable, it might return false when the validation is complete.

Comment: I cahnged it to pristine. I have it now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

On Angular 9, this works for me, with two way binding:

```
<input type="date" class="form-control" name="birthDate" [(ngModel)]="matterData.birthDate" [ngModel]="matterData.birthDate | date:'dd/MM/yyyy'" required>
```

Answer (score -1):

Ref - [Using Pipes within ngModel on INPUT Elements in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39642882/using-pipes-within-ngmodel-on-input-elements-in-angular)

`<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="ex. MM/DD/YYYY" [ngModel]="matterData.birthDate | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy'" (ngModelChange)="matterData.birthDate=$event" name="birthDate">`

Comment: this doesn't work! It formats it correctly when it loads, but as soon as I try and change the date. Ex. remove it, it starts changing the values that aren't correct!

Comment: I understand why it throws an error, it's because it expects any data inside the box to be in the pipe format. So if I have a date and then try and remove a character it will throw an error! and try and fill it back with some other value, maybe some previous value I had in there. Not really sure yet.

Comment: I need to be able to alow the user to modify the field without it throwing errors!