# Angular - Changing the format without change the original value

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

How to format the data just for viewing, but keep the value the way it is?

I have this method that formart the value:

```
formataNomeGrupo(listaGrupoAnaliseCae: SelectItem[]) : any {
         listaGrupoAnaliseCae.forEach((nomeGrupo:SelectItem)=>
             {nomeGrupo.label = nomeGrupo.label.toLowerCase().replace(/(?:^|\s)(?!da|de|do|e)\S/g, l
 => l.toUpperCase());
         });
         return listaGrupoAnaliseCae;
 
     };
```

I call this method here on html :

```
[options]="formataNomeGrupo(listaGrupoAnaliseCae)"
```

For example i have a word, like "DOLAR", and I format this to "Dolar". But i want to keep the value "DOLAR" on my typescript.

Comment: use custom pipe for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use custom pipe

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
@Pipe({
   name: 'lower',
   pure: false
})
export class PersonelFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(param: string): any { 
     return param.toLowerCase().replace(/(?:^|\s)(?!da|de|do|e)\S/g, l=> l.toUpperCase());
   }
}
```

in your html write like `<div>{{label | lower}}</div>`

Comment: i can only do that on {{}}? i can't in a "value=" for example?

Comment: you can check it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39642882/using-pipes-within-ngmodel-on-input-elements-in-angular