# Display whole number with 3 decimal places in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an Angular application which has an input field to enter number. I want to display the number with 3 decimal places if user enters any whole number. For example, if user enters **6**, it should display as **6.000** as soon as user clicks outside the input field.  Is there any angular way to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use blue event in the input field like this:

```
<input (blur)='addDecimals()' [(ngModel)]="usernumber"/>
```

In your component do this:

```
public usernumber;

addDecimals() {
   this.usernumber.toFixed(3); // it will be a string
}
```

The best way to do this is using the decimal Pipe provided by angular, but how to use it is not provided in any answer. You should do this to get it working:

```
<input [ngModel]="item| number:'0.3-3' " 
      (ngModelChange)="item=$event" name="inputField" type="text" />
```

You can check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39642882/using-pipes-within-ngmodel-on-input-elements-in-angular) for more details, how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use angular decimal pipe https://angular.io/api/common/DecimalPipe

```
valueVariable | number:'0.3-3'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use parse float with precision and use an event `keyup` or `focusout` to call a function to convert the number.

```
<input 
    (focusout)="convert($event.target.value)"
></input>
```

```
convert(num){
  this.num = parseFloat(num).toFixed(3); //where this.num is the variable for the said number.
}
```

Comment: will it store it as Number or String?

Comment: toFixed returns a string value, so you will end up having a string representation of the number.

Answer (score 0):

in the HTML section, put the value and then add **number:'0.3-3'**

{{valueName | number:'0.3-3'}}

ps: it's the same answer of @zainhassan

Comment: Don't repost the exact same answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [upvote answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33745505)