# Angular - Apply decimal pipe to an input

Tags: javascript, angular, ngx-mask

I want to apply decimal pipe on an input so the user can see comma separated numbers as he/she types. I have tried the ngx-mask but that only works if you type in the input. When you patch a value to the input it doesn't transform the value into decimal format.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you can use  `ngModelChange` when you value change you can use a pipe in your `ngModel` as below

```
<input [ngModel]="item.value | currency" (ngModelChange)="item.value=$event"
name="name" type="text" />
```

and more detail about it [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42062664/6052427)