# localizedDate pipe in Angular

Tags: angular, mat-datepicker, angular-input

```
<mat-form-field [ngClass]="formFieldHelpers" class="flex-auto">
    <mat-label class="font-base leading-4 font-medium">
        {{ 'HEALTHWALLET.TESTINGCARD.TestedDate' | translate}}
    </mat-label>
    <input matInput [matDatepicker]="tested" name="tested" [disabled]="!isEditable || item.testId"
          [(ngModel)]='item.tested' [max]='maxDate' required>
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="tested"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #tested></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

I am trying to add a date pipe (localizedDate) into the `ngModel` attribut of the above code.

```
<mat-form-field [ngClass]="formFieldHelpers" class="flex-auto">
    <mat-label class="font-base leading-4 font-medium">
        {{ 'HEALTHWALLET.TESTINGCARD.TestedDate' | translate}}
    </mat-label>
    <input matInput [matDatepicker]="tested" name="tested" [disabled]="!isEditable || item.testId"
          (ngModel)="item.tested | localizedDate:'MM/dd/YYYY'" [max]='maxDate' required>
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="tested"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #tested></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Using Pipes within ngModel on INPUT Elements in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39642882/using-pipes-within-ngmodel-on-input-elements-in-angular) and https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax -->
**you can't use Template expression operators (pipe, save navigator) within template statement.**

In your case, this should work :

```js
<input matInput [matDatepicker]="tested" name="tested" [disabled]="!isEditable || item.testId"
             [ngModel]="item.tested | localizedDate:'MM/dd/YYYY'" (ngModelChange)="item.value=$event" [max]='maxDate' required>
```

> The solution here is to split the binding into a one-way binding and
> an event binding - which the syntax [(ngModel)] actually encompasses.
> [] is one-way binding syntax and () is event binding syntax. When used
> together - [()] Angular recognizes this as shorthand and wires up a
> two-way binding in the form of a one-way binding and an event binding
> to a component object value.
> The reason you cannot use [()] with a pipe is that pipes work only
> with one-way bindings. Therefore you must split out the pipe to only
> operate on the one-way binding and handle the event separately.

Comment: I have implemented the above changes and still does not work. I wonder if the [matDatepicker] is where the issue lies.

Comment: And have you tried to add  (dateInput)="$event.value.format('MM/dd/YYYY')" to <input ...>